# Finding the posterior probability of a maximum value from a dirichlet distribution

Tags: dirichlet-process

I have a modeling problem that can be reconceptualized in a simpler way like so:

Imagine I have an infinite urn with red, green, and blue balls in it with the proportions p<sub>r</sub>, p<sub>g</sub>, and p<sub>b</sub> (these probabilities are known).

Next, I hand the urn to another person and ask them to draw a number of balls. Their initial beliefs about the distribution of colors can be regarded as uninformative (Dirichlet of {1,1,1}). After N draws, I ask them to tell me which color ball they believe is the most common color from that urn.

I would like to know two related things:

1) If I know the sequence of balls that the subject has drawn, what is the probability distribution over their belief about each of the three hypotheses (that each color is the most probable to be drawn from the urn)?

2) If I repeated this process a large number of times with different subjects (but the same urn), what proportion of subjects would endorse each color belief (assuming a hardmax choice rule on the hypotheses)?

This is a problem that could be solved relatively trivially by sampling, but because it is one component in a more complex model where the different probabilities of each ball will change very often, I was wondering if an analytic solution exists, and how that might be calculated.

Thank you!

Edit: Clarified the first question

Comment: What do you mean by "distribution over their belief about each of the three color hypothesis?" You said you know the sequence of balls they drew along with their colors, so there's only one answer based on adjusting their prior.

Comment: This would be discretizing the posterior, so the belief that the most common color is red (B_r) would be equal to P(p_r > p_g, p_b). I'm trying to determine what the distribution over B_r, B_g, and B_b is conditioned on a series of observations.